# UITableviewCell touch inner detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell which is subclassed from **[UITableviewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/)**.

I want to touch it and send a web request.

When the request is done,then push to another Controller.

How can I do to achieve it inside the custom cell ?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Seems like need to Click/Tap on the cell.. Hope you're declared custom cell inside datasource method cellForRowAtIndexPath. Haven't you tried didSelectRowAtIndexpath Method for tap Action.

Comment: Use tableview delegate method which is called automatically when a view is "touched" = :) and do your implementation there

Comment: A cell can't push to another controller and this is a good thing.

Comment: i truely know that didSelectRowAtIndexpath that tableiview delegate can work it well.However,i want to intercept that touch event inside the custom cell class .Inside the cell ,i send out the web request.Thus i can make it useful for others